# How to access method by using properties in c#?

Tags: c#, methods, properties

I will give you an example for understanding of my question. 
`transform.translate()` (`transform` is a property and `translate` is a method)
But how transform can access to `translate`.

Example :

```
 class ExampleClass
        {

            public int exampleprop
            { get; }
            public void examplemethod()
            {

            }

        }
```

I want to make just like that : `exampleprop.examplemethod()`

And is there any way to make this.

(thats why i ask this questions is there are kind of code line in unity called `transfom.translate`. And i can't understand it.)

Comment: Can you give us more code to help us understand what you're asking?  Your question is difficult to understand.

Comment: Now i did it...

Comment: Your example makes no sense.  Your property `exampleprop` returns a TYPE of `int`.  The methods available to you after accessing the property will be anything that is available to an `int` (which isn't much).  Your `examplemethod` is a method of the CLASS `ExampleClass`.  If you want to be able to acceess `examplemethod`, then your property would have to return the `ExampleClass` type: `public ExampleClass exampleprop`

Comment: There is no way to call `examplemethod` for `exampleprop`. The only way, something like this would work is when the type of the property is an object.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `exampleprop.examplemethod()` is not valid because `exampleprop` is an `int` and ints do not have a method called `exampleprop`.

The way you would access `examplemethod()` is to first create a new object of type `ExampleClass` then access `examplemethod()` as normal.  Here's an example:

```
class ExampleClass {
    public void ExampleMethod() {
        // code for example method goes here.
    }
}
```

Then somewhere you need to "new up" an `ExampleClass` and call the `ExampleMethod` method.

```
ExampleClass foobar = new ExampleClass();
foobar.ExampleMethod();
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment.But  Is there any way to access without creating object?

Comment: You don't need an object instance if the method is static.

Comment: scott, thank you so much.Thats what i'm talking about.